# How to find Significant columns from dataset?

Tags: python, statistics

I want to know how can we find out which is the significant column among the dataset.
for eg. sepal length, sepal width, petal length, petal width, and species are the columns in dataset which is the significant column among the five of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()

# merge data and target into dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
data['Target'] = iris.target

corelation_values = data.corr()

corr_heatmap = sns.heatmap(corelation_values, xticklabels=data.columns, yticklabels=data.columns)
```

The correlation heatmap output is as the following:
[image]

it is evident that all the other features in iris dataset are highly correlated with each other, so **the most significant feature** (with the most distinctive nature) is **sepal width**.